# Does Telegram support multiple profiles?

Tags: profile, user-accounts, telegram

I have my Username, Profile Name, DP etc. of Telegram to be something familiar to my friends and family members. I don't want to use the same in online channels. Will I be able to have a different profiles, each with different Username, Profile Name, DP etc., so that I can be pseudonymous? I am speaking about multiple profiles under the same account (and same phone number), just like what Instagram or YouTube allows you to  do.

Comment: No. It's not possible as of now.

Comment: @SeverusSnape Upvoting tour comment. Please provide a citation from an authoritative source that this is not possible and that there is no workaround. That can be an answer then.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find a citation. From months of using using Telegram, I know it :) that's why I posted a comment instead of posting an answer ;)

Comment: Ah, the old "we can't prove a negative", lol, and in the end the most authoritative citation we will find on the interwebs is @Severus' first comment